# R Shiny selectInput reactivity with multiple variable output

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, reactive, selectinput

I'm seeking assistance with my shiny dashboard issue. 
Essentially, I have a single selectInput menu, however want to be able to select multiple variables and have them all plotted on the same graph.

At the moment I can get it to plot a single selected variable on the plot.ly graph, however even when I select multiple variables, it will still only plot the first variable selected:

current single variable output
[image]

Additionally, when the app is first run, I get this error until I manually select a variable:

error received when first displayed
[image]

This is a simplified version of the code I'm working with so far:

```
global_indices <- read_excel("Market_Data.xlsx", 
                             sheet = 4,
                             col_names = FALSE, 
                             skip = 5)
global_indices_clean <- global_indicies[,c(1,3,7,9,13,21,23)]
colnames(global_indices_clean) <- c("Date", "Australia", "US", "UK", "Germany", "Japan", "Hong_Kong")
global_indices_2y2 <- global_indices_clean %>% filter(between(Date, now() - years(2), now()))


header <- dashboardHeader(
  title = "Dashboard"
)

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    menuItem("Global Indices",
             tabName = "global_indices")
  )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
  tabItems(
    tabItem(tabName = "global_indices",
            fluidRow(
              box(plotlyOutput("plot_3"), title = "Developed indices", status = "primary", width = 4, ""),
              box(plotlyOutput(""), title = "", status = "primary", width = 4, ""),
              box(plotlyOutput(""), title = "", status = "primary", width = 4, "")
            ),
            fluidRow(
              box(selectInput("global_indices_input", "Indices", 
                              choices = 
                                list("Australia" = "Australia", 
                                     "US" = "US",
                                     "UK" = "UK", 
                                     "Germany" = "Germany",
                                     "Japan" = "Japan",
                                     "Hong Kong" = "Hong_Kong"),
                              multiple = TRUE), 
                  width = 4)
            )
    )
  )  
)


ui <- dashboardPage(
  header,
  sidebar,
  body
)


server <- function(input, output) {


  output$plot_3 <- renderPlotly({
    plot_3 <- plot_ly(
      global_indices_2y2, x = global_indices_2y2$Date, y = ~get(input$global_indices_input), type="scatter", mode="lines"
    )
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I can't provide the dataset itself, however below is a small section of it:

```
> str(global_indices_2y2)
'data.frame':   478 obs. of  7 variables:
 $ Date     : POSIXct, format: "2018-01-29" "2018-01-30" "2018-01-31" "2018-02-01" ...
 $ Australia: num  107 106 106 107 108 ...
 $ US       : num  113 112 112 112 110 ...
 $ UK       : num  104 103 102 102 101 ...
 $ Germany  : num  103.9 102.9 102.8 101.4 99.7 ...
 $ Japan    : num  116 114 113 115 114 ...
 $ Hong_Kong: num  120 118 119 118 118 ...
```

I've read through dozens of threads on here over the last few days, however they all seem to focus on issues around multiple selectInput parameters, instead of a single selectInput requiring the ability to select and display multiple outputs.

Any help that you are able to provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: hi, please use ```dput``` rather than ```str``` to provide the code necessary to reproduce your data

Comment: Apologies! Will certainly do this in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach would be to create a separate `reactive` to filter your data, and use the filtered data in your plot. First, I would consider converting your data to long format (e.g., using `tidyverse` `pivot_longer`). For example:

```
global_indices_2y2 <- data.frame(
  Date = as.POSIXct(c("2018-01-29", "2018-01-30", "2018-01-31", "2018-02-01")),
  Australia = c(107, 106, 106, 107),
  US = c(113,112,112,112),
  UK = c(104,103,102,102)
) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Date, names_to = "country", values_to = "index")
```

Then add `reactive` to filter based on multiple selections in your `server`:

```
mydata <- reactive({
  global_indices_2y2 %>%
    filter(country %in% input$global_indices_input)
})
```

Then plot filtered data:

```
output$plot_3 <- renderPlotly({
  plot_3 <- plot_ly(
    mydata(), 
    x = ~Date, 
    y = ~index, 
    name = ~country,
    type="scatter", 
    mode="lines"
  )
})
```